# How to get only specific fields in Gitlab API response?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

For example I want to receive only project names:
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/:id/projects?fields=name

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible in the REST API. But, GitLab is working on GraphQL support, and you'd be able to express that in GraphQL.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/

Answer (score 3):

To iterate on Vonc & King Chung Huang 's answers, using the following GraphQL query, you can get only the name field of the projects inside your group :

```graphql
{
  group(fullPath: "your_group_name") {
    projects {
      nodes {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can go to the following URL : https://$gitlab_url/-/graphql-explorer and past the above query

Using [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) & [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) :

```bash
gitlab_url=<your gitlab host>
access_token=<your access token>
group_name=<your group name>

curl -s -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
     -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
     -d '{ 
          "query": "{ group(fullPath: \"'$group_name'\") { projects { nodes { name }}}}"
      }' "https://$gitlab_url/api/graphql" | jq '.'
```

Answer (score 2):

GitLab 1.11 (May 2019) has now introduced a "[basic support for group GraphQL queries](https://about.gitlab.com/2019/05/22/gitlab-11-11-released/#add-basic-support-for-group-graphql-queries) "

> GraphQL APIs allows users to request exactly the data they need, making it possible to get all required data in a limited number of requests.
>
> In this release, GitLab is now supporting basic group information support in the GraphQL API.

See [Issue 60786](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/60786) and documentation: "[Available queries](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/#available-queries)"

> A first iteration of a GraphQL API includes the following queries
>
> - **project** : Within a project it is also possible to fetch a mergeRequest by IID.
> - **group** : Only basic group information is currently supported.